# How to call a C++ templated function with different data types programmatically?

Tags: c++, templates

In my C++ program I need to call a templated function with different data types (`int`, `float`, `double`, `char`, etc.) and run methods `bar1()`, `bar2()`.

How to do it without having to explicitly write the call for each type?

```
foo<int>::bar1()
foo<int>::bar2() 
foo<int>::bar3() 
...


foo<float>::bar1()
foo<float>::bar2() 
foo<float>::bar3() 
...
```

Comment: your question seems to contradict the idea of templates - what exactly are you doing that requires the same operation to be performed for different types in a void function?

Comment: The problem you are trying to solve is just the redundant typing in your code...  Is that an accurate statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since they are `void` functions in your example, can you rewrite them so that the types can be inferred?   Like this:

```
template <class T>
void example(const T& v)
{
   // do something profound and meaningful here.
   foo<T>::bar1();
   foo<T>::bar2();
   foo<T>::bar3();
}
```

Now the template type can be inferred by the argument passed to the function:

```
int x = 0;
double y = 0;
bool b = false;
std::string s = "Hello";

example(x);
example(y);
example(b);
example(s);
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you've designed those functions, the types will need to be specified to some degree.  They can't be inferred.

You may create a single function so the type only needs to be mentioned once.

```
template<typename T>
void do_it()
{
  foo<T>::bar1()
  foo<T>::bar2() 
  foo<T>::bar3()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are after if you are using C++11. Don't know how to do it with C++03, though.

```
template<typename Type>
void printAll()
{
    Foo<Type>::bar1();
    Foo<Type>::bar2();
    Foo<Type>::bar3();
}

template <typename Type, typename Type2, typename... RestTypes>
void printAll()
{
    printAll<Type>();
    printAll<Type2, RestTypes...>();
}


int main()
{
    printAll<int, double, float, string>();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1. In C++03 you would need a bit more boiler plate, in particular the implementation of a typelist (Modern C++ Design, by Alexandrescu has one such implementation, as the Loki library, and probably in boost)

Answer (score 0):

**Metaprogramming**

Make an array that stores all of the data types you want to test. Then, write a loop to output all of your function calls. Finally, compile and run this generated code.

```
string types = ["int", "float", "char", "double"];
for(int j=0; j<4; ++j)
 for(int k=0; k<3; ++k)
  cout << "foo<" << types[j] << ">::bar" << k+1 << "();" << endl
```

Comment: I would be interested in seeing this as real code, but I wonder whether the solution is not more complex than the problem (i.e. write a simple template that calls all the methods for a type and then explicitly call that helper with each required type...

Comment: I added a simple loop to demonstrate my idea. @DavidRodríguez-dribeas

Comment: Ah, ok... I misunderstood that you meant to use *metaprogramming* to generate a type-list and have it looped over *inside* the program (i.e. *metaprogramming* understood as *template metaprogramming*, rather than *preprocessor*)

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use TypeLists. Have a look at [`boost::mpl::vector`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/vector.html), a container of types. Make a recursive function that takes a vector of types as a template parameter (or an iterator of such a vector), then on each following call pass along the iterator to the next type.